# HTTP STATUS 500 - Internal server error (Servlet.init() for servlet [equinoxbridgeservlet] threw exception)

Tags: java, apache, server, war, tomcat8

I have deployed an application on tomcat and on hitting the URL for the same app I receive the exception that `javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [equinoxbridgeservlet]` threw exception and then at the end it says to `refer to the full stack trace in the logs for the root cause`.

I am using Tomcat8 and JDK 1.8 also for my webapp. I have checked and there are no permission issues.

I have tried to review the Tomcat logs which are attached here as well, but I cannot figure out the problem. I have tested the same application on my local and it was able to run fine.

Although from the logs I can see that there are references to eclipse which I don't understand as I have not used eclipse anywhere for generating the WAR file. Log files are as follows:

> CATALINA.OUT

```
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.380 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:28:22 UTC
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.34.0
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /home/bslemerg/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.392 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/conf/logging.properties
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/temp
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.819 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8089"]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.863 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.880 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.887 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1828 ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:19.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
05-Dec-2018 13:59:20.033 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/docs]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.412 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [14,443] milliseconds.
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.483 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/docs] has finished in [15,449] ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.486 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/ROOT]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.604 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [117] ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.604 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/manager]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.837 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/manager] has finished in [233] ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:35.837 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/examples]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:38.658 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/examples] has finished in [2,821] ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:38.661 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/MyWebAPP]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:39.171 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.569 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/bslemerg/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/webapps/MyWebAPP] has finished in [2,908] ms
05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.578 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8089"]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.590 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 21703 ms
```

> localhost.2018-12-05.log

```
05-Dec-2018 13:59:38.630 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
05-Dec-2018 13:59:38.634 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
05-Dec-2018 13:59:38.636 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@54688dd5')
05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.562 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Error while starting Framework
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher$ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(FrameworkLauncher.java:1028)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.564 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Dec-2018 13:59:41.565 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [equinoxbridgeservlet] in web application [/mau] threw load() exception
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Dec-2018 13:59:58.477 SEVERE [http-nio-8089-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Error while starting Framework
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher$ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(FrameworkLauncher.java:1028)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Dec-2018 13:59:58.479 SEVERE [http-nio-8089-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Dec-2018 13:59:58.480 SEVERE [http-nio-8089-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [equinoxbridgeservlet]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> localhost_access_log.2018-12-05.txt

```
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11286
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /asf-logo-wide.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:45 +0000] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - tomcat [05/Dec/2018:13:59:47 +0000] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:47 +0000] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:47 +0000] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
10.168.129.100 - - [05/Dec/2018:13:59:58 +0000] "GET /mau/index HTTP/1.1" 500 3749
```

Apologies if my question is too basic to ask. Would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Could you add some details about the application? Details like what frameworks does it use (spring mvc or other mvc, no mvc at all), is it packaged with maven (if yes it will be easy to track which classes need EclipseStarter). On a quick search I found a camel-eclipse-starter maven dependency, does the application use camel

Comment: It has started working now, I redid the entire deployment and did fresh installations of tomcat, and my JDK as well as making sure the JDK version was exactly as the linux server and that the user starting tomcat had all the permissions. However, I cannot pinpoint the root cause